# How to fadeOut() element while animate() another one on top of it?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of elements with a remove button on each element, I'm trying to make the remove button fadeOut the element while the siblings move to top. The problem is that when I click on remove the elemenent in question fades out but the siblings don't move, they just change position without animation. How can I make them move up while the element above is fading out. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4c82H/

Here's the code:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $element = $(this);    
    var height = $element.height();
    $element.fadeOut(400);
    $element.next().animate({top:'-=' + height + 'px'});
});
```

Thank you!

EDIT:
Some are proposing slideUp, thank you for this, it works, but is there a way to fade the element while others are sliding?

```
$element.fadeOut();
$element.slideUp();
```

Does not work.

Comment: top property doesn't work for elements with static position as it is by default

Answer (score 4):

`slideUp` will do it. I've attached a sample here. http://jsfiddle.net/4c82H/1/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Neta, you should use slideUp() instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/4c82H/3/

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```